# How to sync the device setting between pytorch(python) and libtorch(C++)?

Tags: python, pytorch, libtorch

There is a annoying problem when using a libtorch function in pytorch(python).
The device setting in libtorch is k:CUDA, and its default meaning is CUDA:0.
But when I use it in python pytorch, I want to use other CUDA device, not CUDA:0.
I have changed CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES in python, but this can't effect the libtorch device settings.
Is there any solution for this condition?
Thanks~

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.